# Regex to change text case

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace the text between the tags upcase to its uppercase version.
Is there a way to do it by only using Regex.Replace method? (without using IndexOf)

Below is the code I was trying:

```
string texto = "We are living in a <upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>. We don't have <upcase>anything</upcase> else.";                
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(texto, "<upcase>(.*)</upcase>", "$1".ToUpper()));
```

The expected result is:

```
We are living in YELLOW SUBMARINE. We don't have ANYTHING else.
```

but I get:

```
We are living in yellow submarine. We don't have anything else.
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above? try `"<upcase>(.*?)</upcase>"`

Comment: What is the output ? What do you expect ?

Comment: "We are living in a YELLOW SUBMARINE. We don't..."

Comment: I don't think you can do that with regular expressions.  The `ToUpper` will apply to the "$1" and have no effect.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks, It helped fixing a bug in the tags but it still doesn't change the text between the tags to uppercase, is it possible to do that with that "$1".ToUpper() or something similar?

Comment: @juharr so the most ellegant way would be to get the index of those tags and then replace in the text before removing the tags?

Comment: @vmp Actually you can do it, but you have to use the overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a delegate that allows you to manipulate the matches.  Just check out Avinash's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do like,

```
string str = "We are living in a <upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>. We don't have <upcase>anything</upcase> else.";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=<upcase>).*?(?=</upcase>)",  m => m.ToString().ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(result, "</?upcase>", ""));
```

Output:

```
We are living in a YELLOW SUBMARINE. We don't have ANYTHING else.
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1aGAsm)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=<upcase>).*?(?=</upcase>)` - Matches the text which was present inbetween `<upcase>` ,`</upcase>` tags. `(?<=...)` called [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), here it asserts that the match must be preceded by `<upcase>` string. `(?=</upcase>)` called positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by `</upcase>` string. So the second line of code changes all the matched characters to uppercase and stores the result to the `result` variable.
- `/?` optional `/` (*forward slash*). So the third line of code replaces all the `<upcase>` or `</upcase>` tags present in the `result` variable with an empty string and prints the final output.

Comment: Would you have a link to a reference on that part?

I got a little confused with that many interrogation marks